# Histogram in matplotlib work incorrect

Tags: python, graph, numpy, matplotlib

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
data = [0.6, 0.8, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 0.4, 0.2]  
plt.hist(data, bins=20, range=[0.0, 1.0], normed=True)  
plt.show()
```

And after this i taken histogram, where frequency for every item about 5, not 0.25%. How i can fix this?

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist Are you sure you `normed` kwarg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the histogram result by assigning `plt.hist` as follows:

```
out = plt.hist(data, bins=20)
print out
```

which prints:

```
(array([2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]), 
 array([0.2 , 0.23, 0.26, 0.29, 0.32, 0.35, 0.38, 0.41, 0.44, 0.47, 
        0.5 , 0.53, 0.56, 0.59, 0.62, 0.65, 0.68, 0.71, 0.74, 0.77, 0.8 ]),
<a list of 20 Patch objects>)
```

which is correct.
also:

```
>>> plt.hist(data, bins=4)
    (array([ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]), array([ 0.2 ,  0.35,  0.5 ,  0.65,  0.8 ]), 
    <a list of 4 Patch objects>)
```